# Defining an object using an explicit value constructor

Tags: c++, class, class-constructors

I'm trying to do an exercise using classes to store dates (MM DD YYYY).  I have two class constructors, one default that sets the Date values to a default, and one that uses explicit values sent from `main()` in my driver file.

However, after my declaration statement in `main()` to the explicit value constructor (to make `date2`) in my driver file, I'm getting errors that appear to indicate that `date2` was never made.

Below are the relevant portions for this constructor. How do I get `date2` to become defined and declared to use for other things in `main()`?

**Header**

```
class Date
{
    private:
        int month, day, year;
    public:
        Date(); // default date constructor will assign all data members to equivalent of 01/01/2022
        Date(int initMonth, int initDay, int initYear); //parametered Date constructor will collectively set all three data members
}
```

**Implementation**

```
Date :: Date(): month(1), day(1), year(2022) {}
Date :: Date(int initMonth, int initDay, int initYear)
{
    if (initMonth < 1 || initMonth > 12) { cerr << "Invalid month\n\n"; month = -2; }
    if (initDay < 1 || initDay > 30) { cerr << "Invalid day\n\n"; day = -2; }
    if (initYear < 1) { cerr << "Invalid year\n\n"; year = -2; }
    month = initMonth;
    day = initDay;
    year = initYear;
}
```

**Driver**

```
Date date1;
do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a date in this sequence: MM DD YYYY ";
        cin >> month >> day >> year;
        Date date2(month, day, year);
    } while (date2.month == -2 || date2.day == -2 || date2.year == -2);
    date1.print();
    date2.print();
```

Comment: The scope of `date2` is the body of the `do-while` loop. After the loop exits, the variable is destroyed, so attempting to print it won't show you anything. Perhaps try reading and validating the arguments first, and then constructing the parametrized `Date`? Or you could have a default-initialized `Date` before the loop and in the loop you'd perform an assignment.

Comment: Show the *real* code as a proper [mcve] that includes your formal definitions and driver `main` and the formal definitions of both `date1` and the *other* `date2` (there are two of the latter, otherwise this cannot possibly compile, much less run).

Comment: Write a function that validates those three data before passing them to the constructor. That way you can remove the complexity related to input validation from the constructor's body and place it in a separate function. Constructors should not perform lots of tasks. The less work is done in the body of a constructor, the better and safer it is.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks! Pulling it out of the loop allowed me to preserve the variable

Comment: @digito_evo Appreciate the advice! I'm going to re-write to allow the validation work to occur in a separate class function.

Comment: @coutMyNameIsMatt And that function must be declared `static` so that you can call it without the need for creating an instance of the class like `date2`.

Comment: I had the patience to copy your code and imagine the parts missing, which I added to it. It is on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d2ba273507fcb99 . You can click on "Compile, link and run" to see errors printed on the console. `date2` is declared on an inner scope, unreachable for the `date2.print` statement. And `date1` is not even declared.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, first post. I have edited to show the minimum relevant parts of each.  I was able to correct the issue with Nathan Pierson's advice.

Comment: @sergiol Sorry, first post. I have edited to show the minimum relevant parts of each constructor.  My program is now functioning as intended.